# IE8 Z-Index with Before and After Pseudo Elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, z-index, pseudo-element

I am struggling trying to figure this one out. I have an `article` that has two elements being inserted `:before` and `:after` it that are both being positioned absolutely within that article.

In all browsers except IE8 the z-index stacking is working perfectly. It should go in this order from bottom to top:

Article Content > Fade Out Image > Icon

I have already tried a few different things, the latest of which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/LtYMV/2/

A basic run down of what I'm trying looks like this:

```
article {
    // styles
}

article:before {
    // icon background image used on inserted content
}

article:after {
    // background image used on inserted content
}​
```

I know there is some sort of trick to this I just can't seem to figure it out with any combination of z-index values. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

IE8 is weird when it comes to pseudo elements and z-index. There's a bug that make child elements kind of inherit (without being able to overwrite) the parents' z-index. You can read more about [IE8 and z-index on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html).

I changed your fiddle a bit to work the same way as your example in standards compliant browsers and to work alright in IE8, but without the fade in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/LtYMV/8/, although with the icon *under* the text.

I also created a version where it's using another element for the icon (with the class "icon", just after each ".post" element). It still hasn't got the fade for IE8, but the icon is *over* the text: http://jsfiddle.net/LtYMV/7/, so it's a slight improvement from the previous one.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. In the end, I'm looking for something that makes IE8 look *just* like Chrome does. Unfortunately I've had to switch over to JS to insert `<span>` elements in the place of the before and after pseudo elements for IE8.